# How to move data from one activity to next activity (ListView) by clicking an add button?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am creating a fitness application where the user is allowed to create their own list of workouts and they can do so by clicking a "+" button beside the image view. one clicked, the imageview, textview1 and textview2 should be added to the list view on the next activity. basically when the button is clicked, data should be added to the UserCustomiseWorkout which has a listview

AllExercise Java

```
public class AllExercises extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_exercises);

    ImageButton imagebutton7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    imagebutton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UserCustomiseWorkout.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


public void clickNextExPage(View v)
{
    Intent nextpage = new Intent(this, AllExercises2.class);
    startActivity(nextpage);
}
```

AllExercise XML

'''

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AllExercises">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView11"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/bicyclecrunch" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView12"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView11"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/catpose" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView13"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView11"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/chairpose" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView14"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView12"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/childspose" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView15"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cobblerpose" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView16"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/cobrapushup" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView17"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/crunches" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView18"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView17"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/doubleleglifts" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView19"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView17"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/downwarddogpose" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView20"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView19"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView18"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/glutebridge" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView13"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView15"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView17"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView19"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="152dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="64dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton21"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView14"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton22"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView16"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton23"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView18"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton24"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="58dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="58dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView20"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton25"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="56dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/more" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_ex_page"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:onClick="clickNextExPage"
            android:text="Next Page"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView19" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>   '''
```

UserCustomiseWorkout Java

```
public class UserCustomiseWorkout extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_customise_workout);


}
```

UserCustomiseWorkout XML

```
   ''' <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView31"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout7"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout7"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout7"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout7"
    android:layout_width="313dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView31"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView39"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView40"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout> '''
```

Answer (score 0):

get the text From the text views, create a list , add them to the list, pass the list via intent to the next activity, get the list from the intent. this is a simple way for your problem to work. but maybe for a better approach you would like to add this item to a database and fetch them when need it.

Comment: hi, i did add to realtime firebase database. if so, how do I retrieve it? if possible, can you give me an example code?

Comment: Well in that case you dont need to pass it as an intent and just get it from firebase once you are on the activity , here all you need to know https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: erm it doesnt really help with what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Here In Source Activity from you want to send data add this ,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
//attach the key value pair using putExtra to this intent
String user_name = "Jhon Doe";
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME", user_name);
//starting the activity
startActivity(intent);
```

And in destination activity where you want to get Data

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
//get the attached extras from the intent
//we should use the same key as we used to attach the data.
String user_name = intent.getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
Log.d("User Name",user_name);
```

As like this you can add this part in Adapter by using context reference  or with getApplicationContext() for Activity data transmission.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the code, but it doesn't add to the UserCustomiseWorkout listview.

Comment: And also type of design what you admire

Comment: Im trying to add data from AllExercises to UserCustomiseWorkout

AllExercises Java:

'''public void openUserCustomiseWorkout(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserCustomiseWorkout.class);
        String exercisename = "Bicycle Crunch";
        intent.putExtra("exerciseName", exercisename);
        startActivity(intent);
    }'''

Comment: and receive this by getIntent().getExtra("exerciseName"); @Kris

Comment: '''protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_customise_workout);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String exercisename = intent.getStringExtra("exerciseName");

        Log.d("exerciseName", exercisename);
    }'''

Comment: What you have received in Log for "exerciseName" ?
have you debugged it ? @Kris